# Building wheel for psycopg2-binary (setup.py) error, Running setup.py install for psycopg2-binary error

Tags: postgresql, installation, pip

I previously had python 3.8.3 installed ,so when I ran command git push heroku master

it showed error that python 3.8.3 is not supported ,so I installed the latest version of python 3.10.0 but  when I ran the command git push heroku master ,it showed python manage.py collectstatic no input error .

So i ran python `manage.py collectstatic` command, it showed no module named `psycopg2`
so I ran tried to install `psycopg2` package but it is showing  this error

and  I have also tried to uninstall python 3.8.3 and install python 3.10.0 but still I am getting the error (image 3),and all the packages that I installed are uninstalled,and virtual environment is also not working.

```
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2-binary ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\de\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\de\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z248sguy\\psycopg2-binary_78c223d07cf549a0ac2806ede8a207e1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\de\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z248sguy\\psycopg2-binary_78c223d07cf549a0ac2806ede8a207e1\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if 
os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\de\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s3te9bn_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\de\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psycopg2-binary'
         cwd: C:\Users\de\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z248sguy\psycopg2-binary_78c223d07cf549a0ac2806ede8a207e1\
    Complete output (20 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psycopg2
    copying lib\errorcodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psycopg2
    copying lib\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psycopg2
    copying lib\extensions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psycopg2
    copying lib\extras.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psycopg2
    copying lib\pool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psycopg2
    copying lib\sql.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psycopg2
    copying lib\tz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psycopg2
    copying lib\_ipaddress.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psycopg2
    copying lib\_json.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psycopg2
    copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\de\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\de\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z248sguy\\psycopg2-binary_78c223d07cf549a0ac2806ede8a207e1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\de\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z248sguy\\psycopg2-binary_78c223d07cf549a0ac2806ede8a207e1\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\de\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s3te9bn_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\de\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psycopg2-binary' Check the logs for full command output
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip install psycopg` it worked for me.
don't mention version i.e("pip install psycopg2").

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).